# Write join query DBAccess in swift

Tags: ios, swift, orm, dbaccess

I want to get data like following structure.

[image: Display Record]

// Media table like this::-

```
import UIKit

@objc(Media)

class Media: DBObject {    
    dynamic var media_id : NSNumber!;    
    dynamic var post_id : Post!;    
    dynamic var desc : String!;    
    dynamic var url : String!;
}
```

I want to get data from "**Post**" table with Media list from "**Media**" table.

One post has may be multiple medias **or** it may be not (media list zero).

Please suggest DBAccess Query to get DBResultSet in Swift.

Comment: I have added a specific example to my answer below, using your class description above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a parameter you add to the query, **joinTo**.

Here is the entry from the header file.

```
/**
 * Used to include "joined" data within the query string, you must use the tablename.columnname syntax within a where statement

 *
 * @param (Class)joinTo the class you would like to pwrform a SQL JOIN with
 * @param (NSString*)leftParameter the property name that you would like to use within the local object to match against the target
 * @param (NSString*)targetParameter the property within the class you wish to join with that will be matched with the left parameter.
 * @return (DBQuery*) this value can be discarded or used to nest queries together to form clear and concise statements.
 */
- (DBQuery*)joinTo:(Class)joinClass leftParameter:(NSString*)leftParameter targetParameter:(NSString*)targetParameter;
```

An example in swift, linking two tables (Employee & Login) is below.

```
Employee.query().joinTo(Login, leftParameter: "login", targetParameter: "Id")
```

Obviously, the class can't be changed at runtime, so you find the results in the Dictionary object, **joinedResults**

Although what you are describing is far more to do with relationships, I suggest you look at the one to many examples here:

[Relating two objects in DBAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672092/relating-two-objects-in-dbaccess/29673657#29673657)

So in your specific case, you would add the following method to your Post class.

```
func media -> DBResultSet {
        return Media.query().whereWithFormat("post_id = %@", withParameters: [self.post_id]).fetch()
    }
```

This will look up and return the results from the media table.